# Points exchange between users Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller, model

this is the main idea of my website

> The user **number 1** see a picture he likes(uploaded by user **number 2**) if
>   user **number 1** has enough points(the specific number selected by **user
>   number 2**) he clicks on download link,and gets redirected to the
>   download page...and the user **number 2** who owns the picture gets his
>   points. The way user **number1**,gets his points back is to upload a
>   picture himself,and other users have to download it,so he again has
>   points to download pictures from other user.

The model and their controllers to work here is Picture.rb and User.rb
This is what i tried

1.Add to user model , **“points" column**,make it an integer,it will show the number of points the user has

2.Add to picture model **“points_needed” column**,should be integer as well,show the amount of points needed to download the picture

3.Add to picture model **"picturelink"** column,the users will insert into that field,when uploading a picture the url to their picture,so the users who download can be redirected to that download URL.(like getting to the final page,to the product,after clicking buy now,as an example)

When creating a picture,in picture views, `new.html.erb`
i put

`<%= f.input :picturelink, :placeholder => "Enter the link(URL) to the files you want to share" %>`

and

```
<%= f.number_field :pointsneeded %> # let them select how many points they 
will charge
```

and to show it in show.html.erb,also in picture model
i put

```
<%= @picture.picturelink %> #shows the Url of the picture download page(it will be hidden later)
```

and

```
<%= @picture.pointsneeded %> #show the points needed to get this picture
```

and it shows everything perfectly

> **Question:** How can I make,when user **number 1** wants to download a picture owned by user **number 2**,if user **nr.1** clicks **"get
>   this picture button"** he gets redirected to the download page,and the
>   points are transferred to user **number 2** the picture's owner.

**Edit after trying the given solutions:**
after clicking on

```
<%= link_to "Get this picture", download_picture_path(@picture) %>
```

I keep getting

```
undefined method `pointsneeded' for #<Picture::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8e20193ba0>
```

This is what i used in my Picture Controller

```
  def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      current_user.points -= @picture.pointsneeded #this line gives error,and the next
      @picture.user.points += @picture.pointsneeded
      current_user.save
      @picture.user.save
      redirect_to @picture.picturelink #redirect to the final picture
    end
  end
```

Routes

```
get '/downloadpage/:picture_id' => "pictures#downloadpage", as: :download_picture
```

**

> Final solution:

** 
change the routes to(note i use :id,not :picture_id)

```
get '/downloadpage/:id' => "pictures#downloadpage", as: :download_picture
```

in controller add(the show,edit...are not important,they are just for my app needed),i added :download page

```
before_action :find_picture, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update, :upvote, :downloadpage]
```

And that's it,it worked,thanks to @Mario,for more details on how i solved this question,look into our chat,link located into @Mario and me sub-comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to control the entire experience you would send the buying user to a `download` action in your PicturesController.

Inside this action you'd use a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) to remove points from the 'buying' user and give them to the 'selling' user like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    current_user.points -= @picture.pointsneeded
    @picture.owner.points += @picture.pointsneeded
    current_user.save
    @picture.owner.save
end
```

replacing `current_user` and `@picture.owner` to whatever you call the buying and selling users, respectively. Using a transaction ensures that BOTH the removal and addition of points happen, or otherwise **neither** will happen. Imagine if a user lost points while no one gained! Imagine if this was money! That'd be catastrophic. You use transactions when you want to ensure everything is saved or rolled back if an error occurs.

and then either use `redirect_to` to send them to the `@picture.picturelink` directly OR, if you want to hide the direct link from the buying user (which I think is  a good idea to protect the 'seller') you could use something like:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = @picture.picturelink
data = open(url).read
send_data data, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename=> "#{@picture.name}.#{@picture.picturelink.split('.').last}"
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bit overkill for this application, but when doing "transactions" (in the sense of transfers from one account to another), it's a good idea to also keep a transaction log that can be audited for mistakes.  You could also add a transaction log entry within the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`.

Comment: @Mario where would you add the owner column to the user model,or to picture model? thanks.

Comment: @MikeMcCallen That would be a belongs_to on the Picture model, and a has_many on the User model. The column always goes on the belongs_to, so the Picture model. It would be named depending on what you name the relationship (if you use :owner, it'd be owner_id) but Rails has a helper: t.references :owner (use the relationship name)

Comment: currently i have user_id in my Picture model,and all the relatioships are in place as you say.I suppose considering that I already have user_id in picture model,I should't create and add another owner_id...so i can just use @picture.user.points as in your example instead of owner.So by this logic i won't have (seller and buyer,because my users are both),but instead i will have to use current_user "as buyer" and user "as seller" right?

Comment: @MikeMcCallen Correct. Alternatively if you don't wanna change the name of that column, but you want to be able to do @picture.owner, you could change your current belongs_to relationship to say `belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"`

Comment: @Mario I did everything as you said,I almost got the task done,but there is this error,please take a look into my "Edited question" ,thank you for your help.

Comment: @MikeMcCallen It's saying that `pointsneeded` doesn't exist in your Picture model... what's the name of the attribute you're saving the points it costs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77352/discussion-between-mike-mccallen-and-mario).

Answer (score 2):

Marios answer is great (never knew about transactions). The only thing I can add if you don't know, is you need to make a new route in `routes.rb` to your download action in your `PicturesController` in order for the **"get this picture button"** to work.

Comment: Would you add in routes something like that...  get 'pictures/downloadpage' => 'pictures#downloadpage' .... ? ,thanks.

Comment: Yea, but it may make more sense to call it something like `get '/download/:picture_id' => "pictures#download", as: :download_picture`. Then in you view do `download_picture_path (@picture)` and that gives you the picture in question for you download action